# PHP Simple Contact Form Not Working Not Sure WHY

Tags: php, ajax, forms, contacts

Cant seem to see why this contact form is not working any pointers would be great... wanna send the form via ajax and serialise the data to be sent across.. just doesnt seem to be working though..hope some one can help

html

```
<form method="post" action="" id="contact_form">
  <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <label for="contact_name">Your Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="contact_name" name="contact_name" class="required">
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <label for="contact_email">Your Email</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="contact_email" name="contact_email" class="required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <label for="contact_company">Company Name or Organization</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="contact_company" name="contact_company" class="required">
                </div>
                <div class="large-6 columns">
                    <label for="contact_phone">Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="" id="contact_phone" name="contact_phone" class="required">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <label for="contact_message">Your Message</label>
                    <textarea rows="4" placeholder="" id="contact_message" name="contact_message" class="required"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="large-12 columns">
                    <input type="submit" name="contact_submit" id="contact_submit" value="SEND MESSAGE" class="button">
                </div>
            </div>

        </form>

        <p class="success" style="display:none">Your message has been 
               sent successfully.</p>
```

Mail.php

```
    <?php 

$name =  $POST['contact_name'] ;
$email = $POST['contact_email'] ;
$company = $_POST['contact_company'] ;
$number = $_POST['contact_phone'] ;
$message = $POST['contact_message'] ;

mail("allycallow@hotmail.com", $name, $company, $number, $message, "From:" . $email);
    ?>
```

js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#contact_form').validate({

    submitHandler: function(form) {
      //do submit

          var dataString = $("this").serialize();
          //alert (dataString);return false;
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/mail.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
             $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
              $("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
              $('.success').fadeToggle(1000);
        }
      });
          return false;
    }
 });
});
```

Comment: Change `$POST` to `$_POST` and please explain what you have tried already to solve it

Comment: Hi, this calls for basic debugging first. What exactly doesn't work where? What do test outputs show you in JavaScript and PHP - is the request ever made? Is the data ever transmitted?

Comment: ive it working now, but it seems to send no data and gets put in my junk mail.. weird..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made some mistakes. Use the below code:

```
<?php 
$name =  $_POST['contact_name'] ;
$email = $_POST['contact_email'] ;
$company = $_POST['contact_company'] ;
$number = $_POST['contact_phone'] ;
$message = $_POST['contact_message'] ;

//modify the mail function
mail("allycallow@hotmail.com", $name.$company, $message, "From:" . $email);
?>
```

And in JS change the below:

```
 success: function(returnData) {
      $('.success').fadeIn(1000);
      $("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
      //$('.success').fadeToggle(1000);

    }
```